# how to achieve this effect in the Sketch or affinity-designer?

Tags: sketch-app, affinity-designer

[image]I recently found this theme, and really loved this effect of a gradient inside a glass blur, is there a way and how to achieve this effect in the Sketch or affinity-designer[an icon in that theme called echoes]?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  If you have a specific effect in mind, you should post an example image. Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/134842/edit) and add one, and also mention what you have tried or what has failed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i am really sorry i thought i had attached the photo, but i did it now, i tried on affinity designer when you duplicate and add blur then rasterize and add very low opacity color overlay, it will produce the glass blur for anything behind, but i didnt know how to add the gradient inside on the galss blur, Thanks again

Comment: You might want to add a gradient to your semi-opaque colour overlay.  I'm not a sketch or affinity user, but that is exactly how I would do it using other vector image editing software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the query / issue... if you clip yoyur blurred version of your underlay into the geometry of your glass over the top, you can still apply fills and effects to the geometry of the glass - so you can use a gradient fill on it, you can apply a transparency gradient etc - all whilst it still holds the blurred background in it clipped.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: yess thank you, that really works though not as strong of saturation as above but its really all i wanted.